# canvas animation - not working in loop

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Hello I can't understand the problem that I have

```
private void StartReplay(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 40; i++)
        {
            if (leftCounter < 20)
            {
                leftCounter++;
                leftCounter2 = leftCounter;
                Canvas.SetLeft(Kwadracik, leftCounter);
            }
            else
            {
                leftCounter2--;

                Canvas.SetLeft(Kwadracik, leftCounter2);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now 2 ways

1) If I'll delete the loop than every time I'll click a button the leftCounter will be incremented by 1 and the canvas will be moved. 20 to right than to left as many as many click I'll make. It works as expected. First to the right than to the left

2) When I run it with loop when I click the button the loop will go. But it won't work as I expect it to work. I've expected that it will go 20 to right and than 20 to left (20+20 = 40). But no. It is not moving in two sides. It's just stand because it is jumping to the end. I can't see the move to the right. Even if I'll get small delay on every loop step the GUI is freezing and it is unfreezing after the loop ends and the element is where it was

Why there is this kind of diffrence ? How can I overpass it ?

XAML that is standing behind this

```
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Rectangle Name="Kwadracik" Width="20" Height="20" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Fill="Blue" />
    </Canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are probably calling StartReplay from GUI thread. Thread processing continues only after your function finishes. In other words GUI can not process your changes until your function completes. When you place changes in button click handler which is also gui thread, you exit your function and after that gui reflects changes. That's why first method works click by click.

What you can do is start worker thread and make modifications there or as this seems to be animation-like behavior, use Timers.

**Update:**
Example 1:

DispatcherTimer executes callback in calling thread.

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Threading;


namespace CanvasAnimation
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        DispatcherTimer uiTimer;
        double directionDelta = 1.0;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            uiTimer = new DispatcherTimer(); //This timer is created on GUI thread.
            uiTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(uiTimerTick);
            uiTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1000/25); // 25 ticks per second
            uiTimer.Start();
        }

        private void uiTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double currentLeft = Canvas.GetLeft(Kwadracik);

            if (currentLeft < 0)
            {
                directionDelta = 1.0;
            }
            else if (currentLeft > 80)
            {
                directionDelta = -1.0;
            }

            currentLeft += directionDelta;

            Canvas.SetLeft(Kwadracik, currentLeft);
        }
    }
}
```

Example 2: Using Simple Timer

```
    using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace CanvasAnimation
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for WorkerTimer.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class WorkerTimer : Window
    {
        Timer timer;
        double directionDelta = 1.0;

        public WorkerTimer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer = new Timer(this.timerTick, this, 0, 1000 / 25); // 25 fPS timer
        }

        protected void timerTick(Object stateInfo)
        {
            //This is not a GUI thread!!!!
            //So we need to Invoke delegate with Dispatcher
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new MoveCanvasDelegate(this.moveCanvas), null);
        }

        protected delegate void MoveCanvasDelegate();
        protected void moveCanvas()
        {
            //This function must be called on GUI thread!!!

            double currentLeft = Canvas.GetLeft(Kwadracik);

            if (currentLeft < 0)
            {
                directionDelta = 1.0;
            }
            else if (currentLeft > 80)
            {
                directionDelta = -1.0;
            }

            currentLeft += directionDelta;

            Canvas.SetLeft(Kwadracik, currentLeft);
        }
    }
}
```

The same technique applies to BackgroundWorker or other non-GUI thread.

Comment: yes I'm starting it from GUI cause I'm using button. Ok can you point me how to use Timers for this case ? I neved did this. How can I start worker thread ? I was tring to put it to Task via `Task.Run` but I couldn't update GUI as I got exception that element is owned by other thread

Comment: There is nice DispatcherTimer class which executes callback on calling thread. I'll update the answer